# What tools could I possibly use to make an Android app real-time while using MySQL as database?

Tags: android, mysql, real-time

I have already developed a website mainly using Laravel and MySQL for back-end.

I have built an API using Lumen micro-framework, that is used for the communication between the Laravel app and the database.

What I want now is to create an Android that will be using the same API to communicate with the database. The issue here is that I want the app to be real-time.

Preferably, I would like to develop the Android app using Java, but feel free to recommend any frameworks such as Ionic or any other, that you think will make the task achievable.

Thank you.